# Query single row from join table and total count of joined table

Tags: sql

I have two tables: `accounts` and `users`. `users` references `accounts` through `account_id`. 
What I want to do is get following query to work:

```
`SELECT accounts.*, count(users.*), user.* 
 FROM accounts
 INNER JOIN users on accounts.id = users.account_id
 INNER JOIN users user on accounts.id = user.account_id limit 1
 GROUP BY accounts.id`
```

So, I'll get following results

```
`| accounts.id  | users_count | user.phone |
 ===========================================
 |     1        |      5      |  xxxxxx    |
```

Basically, I want to get quantity of all users inside account and specific data for a single user. Is it even possible to do in a single query?

Comment: so for account.id = 1, you want 5 rows with each user's phone info or a single row with user phones as csv?

Comment: what is your rdms?

Comment: Each account has multiple users, so it doesn't make sense to list an account along with a single user phone number.  Please either show us more expected output, or clarify your question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a single row for each user and account, you can do the following:

```
SELECT accounts.id,usercount.usercount,users.phone
FROM accounts 
INNER JOIN users 
ON accounts.id = users.account_id
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT count(*) usercount,users.account_id
  FROM users
  GROUP BY account_id
) usercount
on usercount.account_id = accounts.id
```

If you want data for any single user within the account, you can use get `MAX(users.id)` to get any user for an account and then fetch data for that user in the result.

```
SELECT accounts.id,usercount.usercount,users.phone
FROM accounts
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT count(*) usercount,users.account_id,MAX(users.id) as userid
  FROM users
  GROUP BY account_id
) usercount
on usercount.account_id = accounts.id
INNER JOIN users 
ON accounts.id = users.account_id AND usercount.userid = users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL-server, you can try this with note.

```
SELECT src.*, user.*, userCount.cnt  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id from accounts)src INNER JOIN
user ON src.id = user1.account_id
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM users WHERE account_id = src.id) userCount
```

it doesn't make sense for you to group by accounts.id, otherwise you can never have all the rows of the users. you can rather group by accounts.id and other fields of user, but it end up you will not have correct row count.

in case your account_id is duplicated in the account table, you need to distinct it at the beginning (in this example it just distinct and fetched id, you may need to distinct more columns.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT      D1.id, D2.phone,
           (Select Count(*) From Users D3 where D3.account_id = D1.id)  as cnt
FROM       Accounts D1
INNER JOIN Users  D2
  ON       D1.id = D2.account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    SELECT t.*,
    (SELECT s.* FROM users AS s WHERE s.account_id = t.id LIMIT 1)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT a.*, COUNT(u.*) AS user_count
           FROM accounts AS a INNER JOIN users AS u ON a.id = u.account_id
           GROUP BY u.id
    ) AS t;
```